# Codename one : access to log file denied on Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, codenameone

I sent an iOS build as usual last Friday. As it failed, now two days later I am trying to access to the error log but I get an access denied so I can't read the log.

Is there anything wrong with my account or it is something more general to CN1?

Here is the error from AWS :

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>Hex number</RequestId>
<HostId>
Very long gibberish string
</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Edit : one hour later :**

It seems like only this specific build is concerned. If I send a new build now the log file is available. So problem is gone for me. Feel free to delete my question.

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow that are potentially useful to future visitors may be worth keeping, and solving.  What does the URL look like? Does it have a `Signature=` or `X-Amz-Signature=` in the URL?  Are the log files for *older* builds still accessible? Perhaps they are only stored for a short time?  `AccessDenied` on a deliberately unsigned URL usually means the object doesn't exist. (The gibberish is for AWS support to internally debug.)  Otherwise, we can close this as a problem that can no longer be reproduced or, I believe, you can delete the question yourself since it has no answers.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment. The older builds are not accessible. I let the question open until someone from Codename One sees it just in case they find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Codename One builds and error logs are wiped automatically within 3 days with no exceptions. This is both a security policy and a cost cutting policy (lower storage costs).

If you need a file you can download it within that timeframe after that it's gone.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information Shai, it's always good to know what policy is applied. However FYI in that case the build was sent around 3PM (Paris) on Friday 27th  and on Monday (30th)  morning the Build Error appeared on the dashboard but the log file was not there. It's the only AWS error I've encountered within a nearly a year of CN1 useage so it just suprised me. Anyway CN1 rocks!

Comment: Thanks. We use AWS for automatic purging and I think it does it on a specific time of day.